# Intellj enabling gradle project refresh output to console

Tags: intellij-idea

My Intellij IDE started taking more than 1/2 hour just to refresh project dependencies just for a project with couple of sub projects.

Same project on command prompt takes less than 5 minutes to refresh all dependencies from command prompt.

Is their any way to get detailed logs of Intellij IDE of actions its performing in background.

I already tried Windows -> Background Tasks -> Show as suggested in following article

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/working-with-background-tasks.html

but it actually that popup doesn't show anything in details which can be helpful to track root cause of delay.

Comment: @CrazyCoder can you please provide link of solution on the basis of which you have marked problem as duplicate.

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA has no option to show Gradle refresh output, your question is exactly the same as the one it's marked the duplicate of.